# Select data from foreign key in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have model

```cs
[Key]
[MaxLength(30), DisallowNull]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Xin vui lòng nhập mã nhân viên")]
public string CODE_EMP { get; set; } //MÃ NHÂN VIÊN

[MaxLength(50), DisallowNull]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Xin vui lòng nhập tên")]
public string NAME_EMP { get; set; } //TÊN NHÂN VIÊN

[DisallowNull]
[StringLength(maximumLength: 250, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Bạn cần nhập mật khẩu từ 6 đến 20 ký tự!")]
public string PASS_EMP { get; set; } //MẬT KHẨU

[DataType(DataType.Date), DisallowNull]
public string BIRTHDAY_EMP { get; set; } //NGÀY SINH

[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Đây không phải địa chỉ email")]
[DisallowNull]
public string EMAIL_EMP { get; set; } //email nhân viên

public virtual Department Department { get; set; } 

public virtual Jobtitle jobtitle { get; set; } 

public virtual EDUCATIONLEVEL EDUCATIONLEVEL { get; set; }

public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; } 

public virtual Majors majors { get; set; } 

public virtual Salary Salary { get; set; }
```

Every time I create a new employee, my foreign key is always null and it is not saved to my database. How do I deal with it?

[image]

Comment: please avoid posting comments to answers in Vietnamese, this is English-only resource. also question lacks details about context, relations between entities etc. *Every time I create a new employee* where is that code?

Comment: oh sorry, i don't know. I create a new employee after running the project according to the model I created above.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have table `Employee` with primary key and foreign keys like these

```
EmployeeID (Primary key)

DepartmentID (Foreign key)
EmployementContractID (Foreign key)
EducationLevelID (Foreign key)
```

You must have 3 screens for creating `Department`, `EmployeeContract`, `EducationLevel` firstly. Then you have a screen for creating new employee.

You should naming fields follow a convention, not `CODE_EMP`, `Jobtitle`, `EDUCATIONLEVEL`.

Comment: I having 3  screens  Department, EmployeeContract, EducationLevel public string CODE_DPM { get; set; } public string NAME_DPM { get; set; }  public string Address_DPM { get; set; }  public string Phone_DPM { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the table relation on the context?

If you dont, you must do something like that on context for each relation:

```
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    
builder.Entity<Employee>(builder =>
{
builder.HasOne(c => c.Departments)
});
```

Comment: No No, my mean is change after run project